# Python Code for Multi class label classification for Images saved in multiple folders, all zipped into one

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

How do you load the images in png format in python which is currently in one zip folder and then set labels/classes to the dataset based on the various folder names, each folder name representing a class. For Eg- Folder names are cars, plants, flowers, coins

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` [docs](http://You%20can%20use%20%60tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory%60)

Call it twice to create both training and validation sets like so:

```
image_dir = 'c:/some_image_directory.zip'
train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(image_dir, 
                                                            subset='training',
                                                            validation_split=0.2,
                                                            shuffle=True,
                                                            seed=42)
validation = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(image_dir, 
                                                            subset='validation',
                                                            validation_split=0.2
                                                            seed=42)
```

Can have issues if you have png images with transparency. You'll have to convert them from 4 channels to 3.

Also not sure how well it will deal with zip folders, should work fine, but if fails you might need to unzip.